# With intuition from $f(x)$ to $f(ix)$: Is there a graphical way?

Tags: complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

Assume a function $f\in F$ is given, where $F$ is the set of all infinitly often continuous differentiable functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which we can create a taylor series that works for the complete function. I restrict my question to these functions.

Such a function may look like this first example $f_1(x)$:

[image]

Or like the second example $f_2(x)$:

[image]

As far as I know it would be sufficient to know everything of these functions if only this graphical representation is given (with an infinite precision; and for all $x$ values). I could calculate / read every value and also the taylor series, because I could calculate / read the derivative at any place (assuming again with a very high accuracy).

This means I could do anything with these functions. This graphical representation is equivalent to an analytical expression.

Now we do something tricky: If we can approximate or calculate the taylor series, we can use complex arguments for the given functions. Let us now draw $f_1(ix)$ and $f_2(ix)$:

$f_1(ix)$:

[image]

$f_2(ix)$:

[image]

Probably now you see: $f_1(x)=\exp(x)$ and $f_2(x)=x^2$

Finally my question is now:

The first graphical representation contains everything about the input function. We can calculate a taylor series for all these functions (assuming we can calculate as many taylor terms as we like with a high accuracy; this can be done with the tangent, whcih we can measure). Given this taylor series we can also use values from $\mathbb{C}$ to evaluate this function. If we do this, we get the last two images. So: Is there an intuitive way that is only based on "graphical operation" to get the plot $f(ix)$ given the plot of $f(x)$ (for any $f\in F$)? This means without doing any calculations.

Thank you very much

Comment: From the complex analysis point of view, this means that $f$ is what is called an "entire" function which is real on the real line. One thing you get is that $f(-ix)=\overline{f(ix)}$. Most of the results you might like are in complex analysis. There is a geometry going on here, but it might be hard to describe.

Comment: When you plot a complex function you should plot $\Im (z) ~\text{vs.} ~\Re (z)$. The range of behavior that you can get with $f(x)~\mapsto~f(ix)$ is too broad to characterize generally. In your examples, $f_1$ maps to a circle and $f_2$ maps to itself, essentially.